# what is the ideal way to edit a single file on github?

Tags: git, github

I currently have a running rails application. One other programmer meddled with things like the .gitignore files and committed files that I don't should be committed.

I, myself, am already handling the project to him. I wouldn't want mess up if he was doing anything really important. But I need to modify a file and won't want to push his files to the server.

What can I do to just edit that file and push that file to the staging server without pulling his code?

Comment: Create another branch for yourself! If you are committing code to the same branch, you will have to pull all the changes that are already in the server to be able to push yours.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I was worried I'd be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create another branch from the last commit you want

```
git checkout -b branch-name 0451d7fc32
```

This will switch to an old commit and create a branch. Push this and pull this from your staging with:

```
git pull origin branch-name
```

Then switch to it.

```
git checkout branch-name
```